# Best practice for writing with primary key constraint?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Before each Update/Insert statement, should I :

- IF...EXIST to test the primary key
- Just let a transaction fail if primary key is already there (and rely on @@rowcount if I
  have some logic related to primary key already being there)
- TRY ... CATCH an error (raised by the Update/Insert statement itself or have a trigger test primary key and raise errors)
- Other solutions ?

How do you write with primary key constraint ?

Comment: Are you looking to be processing many or single rows here? The methodology for processing a single row for an UPSERT compared to many is can a little different.

Comment: See [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) and [Checking for potential constraint violations before entering TRY/CATCH](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and, more generally, before you start thinking about implementing `MERGE`: [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred method for single-row upsert is:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE dbo.t WITH (HOLDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
  SET ...
  WHERE [key] = @key;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.t ...
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

If you believe you will much more often be performing an insert, you can swap the logic around so you try that first:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 
INSERT dbo.t ...
  SELECT @key, ...
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.t WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
      WHERE [key] = @key
  );
 
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.t SET val = @val WHERE [key] = @key;
END
 
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Some background:

- [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)
- [Checking for potential constraint violations before entering TRY/CATCH](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is often called an "UPSERT" (in case you need a Google term for further research).

We use [`MERGE` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), since they allow us to specify both actions in one statement.

However, the syntax is a bit complex and there [are some gotchas](https://sqlblog.org/merge) (don't forget to use `HOLDLOCK`, etc.), so we have abstracted away the actual SQL generation into an `InsertOrUpdate(table, fieldsAndValuesToUpdate, keyFieldsAndValues)` helper method in our source code. This also allows us to change the implementation later, if required.

When writing SQL code manually, I use `IF...EXISTS` (inside a transaction and also with `HOLDLOCK`), since it's easier to read and easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the situation.
Suppose you would write an `insert` with a `where not exists` clause and when @@rowcount = 0 you would do an `update` because this row already seems to exist.

If this is the most performant way to do it, that depends on your data.

if you would know that for example in 80% of the cases the insert would succeed, then this approach would actually perform very good.
If it seems that most of the times an update is needed, then you could turn the code around, do the update and then check the @@rowcount.

This only works off course if you can determine before you start if you will have mostly updates or mostly inserts.

The advantage of this method (certainly when you do update first) is that you do not need to check each row first with an `if...exists` first, you just do you insert/update and find out after if it worked or not. And because you know before that the insert or update will succeed most of the times, you gain performance

Comment: I still think the best approach is `UPDATE ... IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT`. Even at 20% failure rate, error handling is expensive.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes off course, I edited my answer already some time ago to use the @@rowcount in case you start with update.

Comment: I was commenting on the "use try catch" and "would actually perform very good"... the [second link in my answer](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) shows that TRY/CATCH except in the 95th percentile or so (meaning it's only better to do that when almost every insert succeeds). Again: error handling is expensive.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I see now, the idea is the same but using a try..catch will cost to much that performance is bad again. I edited my answer